# ffmpeg perspective filter animation error

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a pseudo-3d pan effect in ffmpeg using the perspective filter.

Here is a sample for the starting point...

```
ffmpeg -y -filter-complex "color=black:s=1600x900,trim=0:5,drawgrid=width=100:height=100:thickness=2:color=white,perspective=x0=200:y0=200:x1=1600:y1=0:x2=200:y2=700:x3=1600:y3=900[skew]" -an -map [skew] "skew-start.mp4"
```

And here is a sample for the end point...

```
ffmpeg -y -filter-complex "color=black:s=1600x900,trim=0:5,drawgrid=width=100:height=100:thickness=2:color=white,perspective=x0=0:y0=0:x1=1600:y1=0:x2=0:y2=900:x3=1600:y3=900[skew]" -an -map [skew] "skew-end.mp4"
```

So far so good. Adding the animation would give this...

```
ffmpeg -y -filter-complex "color=black:s=1600x900,trim=0:5,drawgrid=width=100:height=100:thickness=2:color=white,perspective=eval=frame:x0='200-(200*t/5)':y0='200-(200*t/5)':x1=1600:y1=0:x2='200-(200*t/5)':y2='700+(200*t/5)':x3=1600:y3=900[skew]" -an -map [skew] skew.mp4
```

This is where the problem occurs. I get an error saying `[Eval @ 000000f36ebfebf0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 't/5)' Error while filtering: Invalid argument`

The [perspective docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#perspective) say it should work with an `eval=frame` option. Anyone got any ideas? Does this look like a bug in ffmpeg? I'm using the latest version, 4.3.2.

Comment: Here's an example of a scale filter animation which works so my problem seems to be limited to the perspective filter...
```
ffmpeg -filter_complex "color=black:s=1600x900,trim=0:5,drawgrid=width=100:height=100:thickness=2:color=white,scale=eval=frame:w=800+(800*t/5):h=450+(450*t/5)[skew]" -an -map [skew] skew-zoom.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs say,

```
The expressions can use the following variables:

W
H

    the width and height of video frame. 
in

    Input frame count. 
on

    Output frame count.
```

`t` is not one of the allowed variables. Use `in` where `in` is an integer representing time x fps. I could add time but give me a few days to push that.

Comment: Yup, that worked. In how I'm using it I'm going to know the frame rate in advance so I don't need the 't' variable. Thanks!

Comment: Only a safe conversion for constant frame rate videos.